# Javascript file cannot be loaded using relative path with dots

Tags: javascript, html, go

So I do have this projects stucture:

[image]

The HTML `index.html` file I've written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <head>
        XD
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/app.js"></script>
    <button type="button" onclick="XD()">
        XD</button>
</body>

</html>
```

`app.js` file:

```
function XD() {
    console.log("XD")
}
```

And finally `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("tmpl")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

After building and running the application (with all permissions from firewall etc.) when I go to `localhost:8080` the page with header and button loads. But in dev console I can see the following messages:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/static/js/app.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/static/js/app.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Well I thought it may be have something to do with wrong relative path (although when I go Ctrl+LeftClick, then VSCode gets me exactly to `app.js` file). I moved the `app.js` file to `tmpl/` dir and changed the path in `index.html` to just `src="app.js"`. Surprisingly it worked, `XD` was printed into the console. Now am I doing something wrong? Or should the `.js` files be in the same directory tree as `.html` files?

Comment: It helps if you read the error message properly... `was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)`

Comment: Okay, but why does it work with just moving the file around and changing the path, right?

Comment: You cannot go upper the webroot directory.

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for I guess. Then I have to make some directories in my `tmpl` directory and there places `.js` files, right?

Comment: I reckon it's safer to use absolute paths, because if you ever move one of the files then it breaks.

Comment: Okay, but I cannot use absolute one. If I write `src="/static/js.main.js"` it still cannot find the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong. The problem is the only directory you are making accessible from web `tmpl` directory.

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("tmpl")))
```

So when you are typing `localhost:8080` you are basically browsing files from that directory and the static files are not there. But when you moved `app.js` file to `tmpl` directory it worked because now it is accessible from web.

So you just need to have your static contents inside `tmpl` or more precisely web accessible directory.

**Update**

Above solution describes how to `serve` files(html,css,js etc) from a single directory.
Another way is to `serve` just the static files(css,js etc) and `render` the templates(html). You can have different folder for static file and templates, like you do now.

In `main.go` file

```
func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))

    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./tmpl/index.html")
    tplParsed, _ := template.New("test").Parse(string(tpl))
    tplParsed.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

Here we are serving static files in `http://localhost:5000/static` endpoint. So in your `index.html` file `app.js` link should be `/static/js/app.js`.

Note that we are not serving html file directly, instead we are rendering it using [http/template package](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/). Similarly you can render your other template files as well. Hope that help!

Comment: Okay, but I can see some github repos having both `templ` and `static` dirs in the root directory. So I guess there is some kind of workaround, right?

Comment: @Frynio you are right. I have updated the answer, have a look. Let me know if this works for you now.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I was looking for